# Implement SSL in iOS using Secure transport API

Tags: iphone, ios, ssl

I want to implement SSL in my app using Secure transport https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/Security/Reference/secureTransportRef/Reference/reference.html. I want to check for the handshake, session key and encryption(128/256). I am able to verify the certificate using nsurlconnection delegate methods. But need to setup the ssl without using any third party library like ASIHttpRequest or AFNetwork. Thanks in advance

Comment: Is there a specific reason why `NSURLConnection` with a HTTPS URL is not adequate for your needs?

Comment: [http://stackoverflow.com/users/24073/neilco] Using NSURLConnection delegate didReceiveAuthenticationChallenge we can verify the SSL certificate. But I want to do the handshake, generate the session key and  encrypt the data. Similar kind of SSL implementation done in the web browser.

Comment: NSURLConnection handles all that for you. Is there a specific reason why you want to roll your own implementation?

Comment: [@neilco]Yes I want to use my local https server. Does using NSURLConnection for SSL, encrypt the data using session key? Where does the session key exist? Can you please tell me the method/function that does the encryption. Please correct me if I am wrong in something.